# This page is insecure (broken HTTPS) hosting website on 000webhost

Tags: wordpress, http, https, cname

Changed the general settings of my wordpress website: "WordPress Address (URL)" and "Site Address (URL)" to [www.wikipickr.com](https://www.wikipickr.com). After saving when I opened my website the https in url was crossed clicked on it and then details and this was displayed.

[Problem Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HOCHa.png)

**What I wanted:** I wanted the green padlock to appear before the url which meant that the connection is encrypted. And I wanted visitors to stay on www.wikipickr.com domain not the 000webhost domain I mentioned below, as before changing the setting, they were being redirected to `wikipickr.000webhost.com`.

**Things you might need to know:** I own www.wikipickr.com from Go Daddy. I'm actually hosting my website on a free hosting provider, 000webhost. My URL for that site is [wikipickr.000webhostapp.com][3] . I added a `CNAME` record in 
my Go Daddy DNS setting to `wikipickr.000webhostapp.com` and then When I changed the setting from `/wp-admin` as I mentioned above, The cross mark started appearing. This is my first time hosting a website, feel free to bash me for my stupidity, if any. Thankyou for reading all this.

Comment: I dont have enought reputation to post more than 2 links please add https:// to visit the wikipickr.000webhostapp.com

Comment: Both certificate don't match the domain they're used with. One is for `hostingermail.com`, another one is for subdomains of `000webhostapp.com`

Comment: your certificate may not use the www

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't know about certificates, is there a way I can make it work what I wanted? Or else Please guide me where can I learn about certificates if its too much a bother. @Igor Yavych

Comment: Please specify which certificate you are talking about. What I know is that whether I include www or not it still points to my domain. @chop62

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The link you provided now has data base error can not connect you need to follow the instructions provided by godaddy if that is where you purchased your certificate

After you've verified your certificate request, you can download your certificate files, and then install them on your server.

[Install SSL certificates](https://www.godaddy.com/help/install-ssl-certificates-16623)